# Using git command without sudo on CentOS

Tags: centos, git, sudo

I would like to use git without taping sudo everytime i tape a command on CentOS

and i have no idea how to do it.
I checked on google and i found this some command with chown 
but none of them worked

Edited : I don't want to use sudo, i want to use git without taping sudo everytime.
For instance, every time i tape git checkout i have an error of permission and i need to tape sudo git checkout and password to do this

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you edit your post to describe your problem more fully? Why do you need to use `sudo` with `git` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you don't have write permissions on the folder you want to checkout to.

What permissions do you have there? Run

```
ls -la </path/to/gitfolder>
```

You should get something like:

```
$ ls -la /path/to/gitfolder
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 user group 4096 Sep 14 14:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 user group 4096 Sep 14 14:03 ..
```

Here at `.` there should be your user name at `user` and not root (if you run it on your own computer).

If some files are owned by `root`, then you could change the ownership of your current folder and files with this command

```
chown -R <user> .
```

Comment: pwd    
/home/user

    ls -la    
drwxrwxr-x.  4 user user 4096 13 sept. 14:16 Folder


This is what i have in this Folder

Comment: the problem was on the directory it was owned by root indeed
Problem solved with chown -R <user>

Comment: All of that because i've done a git clone with a sudo
I guess doing a git clone with sudo is not the best practice

Comment: @Cornos please use the checkmark next to this answer to indicate that it is the correct answer. This will give OP a few more points, mark this question as solved, and show others with similar questions that this is the solution that worked for you.

Comment: @music2myear thank you for the recall, but do you mean that the green check mean solved or i should edit the title with [solved]?

Comment: Only you, the person who asked the question, can decide which answer worked best for you, and so only you have the ability to click the green checkmark. Placing "solved" in the title does nothing and should not be done. Also, I highly recommend you take the quick tour, which explains all this quite nicely: https://superuser.com/tour